# How to detect if is_404() or is_page() or etc...?

Tags: pages, customization

is there any way, to output, like this:

```
echo $current_type;
```

and it gave me:

`is_404()` or `is_page()` or whatever it `is_blabla()`

Comment: Your question was flagged as "unclear what you are asking", and I cast my vote as such. As I asked in your previous question, what are you trying to achieve. As it stands, no one knows what your expected outcome is. Please file an [edit] and explain **why** you need to do this, what are you trying to achieve with the expected outcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_404()` and `is_page()` is simply just conditionals which just checks if a condition exists. Like `is_404()` simply checks if the current page is a 404 page and returns true on success and false on failure.

*VERY IMPORTANT NOTICE: Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false*

You can get objects from the current page by just simply doing a `var_dump` on [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) like for example

```
 <?php
 $queried_object = get_queried_object();
 var_dump( $queried_object );
 ?>
```

**EDIT**

All of these conditionals are set in the `WP_Query` class, and then separately wrapped in a function in [`wp-includes/query.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L0). For instance, `is_404()` is just a wrapper for [`$wp_query->is_404();`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L697)

```
697 /**
698  * Is the query a 404 (returns no results)?
699  *
700  * @see WP_Query::is_404()
701  * @since 1.5.0
702  * @uses $wp_query
703  *
704  * @return bool
705  */
706 function is_404() {
707         global $wp_query;
708 
709         if ( ! isset( $wp_query ) ) {
710                 _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false.' ), '3.1' );
711                 return false;
712         }
713 
714         return $wp_query->is_404();
715 }
```

Comment: and that's what i wanted, to get the string `is_ABCD` whatever is current object. thanks.